# Multiline bind parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

I'm trying the following query from DBeaver (backend is oracle):

```
SELECT  * FROM mytable where mycolumn in (REPLACE( :req_id_list, CHR(13), ','))
```

when it prompts for the value of *req_id_list* I want to paste the values from Excel, which will be one value per line. the query is failing with *ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis*. is there a way to convert the multiline value to a CSV one ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use DBeaver so this is a SQL*Plus example. Basically, you'll have to "split" that multi-line input value into separate rows (that's what subquery in lines #8 - 10 does):

Declaring a bind variable:

```
SQL> var req_id_list varchar2(20)
```

Storing A + carriage return + C into it:

```
SQL> exec :req_id_list := 'A' || chr(13) || 'C';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Query itself (lines #1 - 5 represent sample data; I expect `A` and `C` to be returned as that's what I passed to `req_id_list`):

```
SQL> with mytable (mycolumn) as
  2    (select 'A' from dual union all
  3     select 'B' from dual union all
  4     select 'C' from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from mytable
  8  where mycolumn in (select regexp_substr(replace(:req_id_list, chr(13), '#'), '[^#]+', 1, level)
  9                     from dual
 10                     connect by level <= regexp_count(:req_id_list, chr(13)) + 1
 11                    );

M
-
A
C

SQL>
```

Comment: still ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis coming up. my guess is that DBeaver is screwing the substitution somehow !